# Mysql double join update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have three tables: objects, relations, points

Relations table connects multiple points to objects. Imagine table structure like this:

```
**OBJECTS**
  |object_id|object_name|object_points|
**RELATIONS**
  |relation_id|relation_object_id|relation_point_id|
**POINTS**
  |point_id|point_value(INT)|
```

No how can i make "double join" in UPDATE to renew object table field `object_points` from total sum of related `point_values`?

Comment: Do you really need that? It is denormalized information, already in the database.

Comment: Yes, in need relations for managment, and object field value for ordering. Could order with join, but it is slower :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE
        Objects AS o
    JOIN
        ( SELECT 
              r.relation_object_id
            , SUM(point_value) AS total_points
          FROM
                  Relations AS r
              JOIN
                  Points AS p
                ON p.point_id = relation_point_id 
          GROUP BY
              r.relation_object_id
        ) AS grp
      ON grp.relation_object_id = o.object_id
SET
    o.object_points = grp.total_points ;
```

Comment: Woow, taht query was amazingly fast! Never imagined i could join with subquery - great refererence. Good job !

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Update OBJECTS set object_points=(select sum(POINTS.point_value) 
  from RELATIONS,POINTS where 
  RELATIONS.relation_object_id=OBJECTS.object_id 
  and RELATIONS.relation_point_id=POINTS.point_id group by relation_object_id)
```

here is the working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2a9f/1/0